# Is there something like Future.wait for streams? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have multiple streams which I am waiting for to be completed. I wanted to know that is there a similar method like Future.wait for the streams? because I searched a lot but found nothing at all.

Comment: I want to achieve something like this I asked here but I don't know how. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778446/flutter-fetch-a-list-of-news-using-stream

Comment: [`package:async`](https://pub.dev/packages/async) has a [`StreamGroup` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamGroup-class.html) that merges multiple `Stream`s into a single one and a [`StreamZip` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html) that returns a `Stream` where the *n*th element is a `List` of the *n*th elements emitted by each input `Stream`.

Comment: Or if you just want to wait for all `Stream`s to complete, you could do something like `await Future.wait([stream1.drain(), stream2.drain(), stream3.drain()]);` (or use `.toList()` instead of `.drain()` if you want to collect the results).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Actually, you can use `Future.wait()` itself. Just wait for stream subscriptions turned into futures:

```
StreamSubscription sub1 = stream1.listen(...);
StreamSubscription sub2 = stream2.listen(...);
await Future.wait([sub1.asFuture(), sub2.asFuture()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're waiting for the streams to be completed, but if you are only interested in the first element of the stream you can also use `first`:

```dart
await Future.wait([stream1.first, stream2.first]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for all streams to complete then:

```dart
await Future.wait([stream1.drain<void>(), stream2.drain<void>()]);
```